# ePDQ error - HTTP response - http result = -1

Tags: php, payment-gateway

I am using ePDQ https://mdepayments.epdq.co.uk as a payment service, and when I'm trying to get the response for the payment, I'm getting an email with this error "Error in HTTP response - http result = -1".

What does this error mean?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like this may be a timeout error. This happened recently to one of our clients, and there was no HTTP error in our logs, so only a timeout or connection error remains (at least according to Barclays helpdesk info we got).

Since the post-sale data has gone through correctly, we've decided to treat this error as a "warning" until proven otherwise.